# How to write data to an xml file from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, xml, xml-parsing, rss

I have an xml file as follows,

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
    <title>XpertDox</title>
 <link>http://localhost:4000</link>
   <description>Find a doctor</description>


 <item>
<title>new feed2</title>           
<link>http://www.espncricinfo.com/</link>
<description>FinddddlklfggfsASAke</description>
</item>



<item>
<title>new feed</title>           
<link>http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/</link>
<description>FinddddlklsASAke</description>
</item>

<item>
<title>w3schoolswdqeqweqw</title>           
<link>http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp</link>
<description>Finddddlklke</description>
</item>



<item>
<title>w3schools</title>           
<link>http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryrss.asp?filename=rss_ex_guid</link>
<description>Finddddlklke</description>
</item>
 </channel>
 </rss>
```

My JS,

```
     getBlogList: function(currentPage, itemsPerPage, base_url) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(base_url+'getBlogList', 
            {params: {currentPage: currentPage,itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage}}).then(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).catch(function(results, status) {
            deferred.reject("An error occured while fetching items");
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    },
```

Here the task is whenever a new  blog  is  added  the  content must come here and how can i achieve that?I completed have no idea of  doing how?If i have a html ,i can easily bind data since its an xml i was confused.Can any one please help me...

Comment: `whenever a new blog` where? and `content must come here` where?

Comment: The content of new blog must come to the rss feed xml file and how to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to create a serverside API. You can't do it in plain Angular. This all depends on what kind of serverside stack you are running.

Comment: i am using node js

Comment: So from server (node js)  I can write sitemap.xml correct? @adrian-brand